# XSLT change value node based on the value of another node

Tags: xslt

I have an XML, something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <earth>
     <computer>
            <parts>
                <cpu>AMD;fast</cpu>
                <video>GF</video>
                <power>slow</power>
                ...others
            </parts>
            <owner>
             <name>Frank</name>
            <owner>
          </computer>

    <earth>
```

I want create xsl transform (xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"). My expected result only if cpu have sign ';' - power should be change to value after ';', if there will not be ';' result should no change

```
<earth>
 <computer>
        <parts>
            <cpu>AMD</cpu>
            <video>GF</video>
            <power>fast</power>
            ...others
        </parts>
        <owner>
          <name>Frank</name>
        <owner>
      </computer>
<earth>
```

Try to do something like this but no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parts">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- try test if node name equals 'power' if equals them try make logic 
                here, this dont work-->
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'power'">
                <xsl:variable name="text" select="./cpu" />
                <xsl:variable name="sep" select="';'" />
                <xsl:variable name="powerTable" select="tokenize($text, $sep)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$powerTable[1]" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!--if not 'power' copy node -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"I have an XML stylesheet"*. May we know how does it looks like? Because the ones posted so far are just the *XMLs*

Comment: I edit my post, I have xml file and need create xsl to transform this file to new xml file with expected result

Comment: Have you attempted to write the XSLT so far? If you have, please share it and explain which part is not working as expected or which part you have no idea how to implement. If you haven't, please read introductory tutorials on XSLT, and try to write one on your own first. Good luck!

Comment: Thx for reply, I create template for parts, try to test there if node name equals power, but this dont work. All others node should be copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following templates to accomplish this :

```
<xsl:template match="parts[contains(cpu,';')]/power">
    <power>
        <xsl:value-of select="../cpu/substring-after(.,';')"/>
    </power>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpu[contains(.,';')]">
    <cpu>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,';')"/>
    </cpu>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template matches *`power` element that is direct child of `parts`* (`parts/power`), where the *`parts` has child element `cpu` that contains character `;`* (`parts[contains(cpu,';')]`). This template will output `power` element with the value from `cpu` element value, after character `;`.

The second template, matches *`cpu` element that contains character `;`*, and outputs `cpu` element with the initial value, before character `;`.

The other template is just identity template which I assume you knew the purpose.